# Remove DEBUG information from amazon mws php api

Tags: php, php-curl, amazon-mws

When I am using the Amazon MWS php API in a linux cli the code is returning a load of bebug information - output starts with:-

```
About to connect() to mws.amazonservices.co.uk port 443 (#0)
Trying 178.236.4.102... connected
Connected to mws.amazonservices.co.uk (178.236.4.102) port 443 (#0)
Initializing NSS with cer....
```

Actual PHP Code is as follows:-

```
include_once ('MarketplaceWebService/.config.inc.php');  

function SubmitFeed(MarketplaceWebService_Interface $service, $request) 
{
try {
        $response = $service->submitFeed($request);
          if ($response->isSetSubmitFeedResult()) { 
              $submitFeedResult = $response->getSubmitFeedResult();
              if ($submitFeedResult->isSetFeedSubmissionInfo()) { 
                  $feedSubmissionInfo = $submitFeedResult->getFeedSubmissionInfo();
                  if ($feedSubmissionInfo->isSetFeedSubmissionId()) 
                  {
                      return $feedSubmissionInfo->getFeedSubmissionId();
                  }
              } 
          } 
} catch (MarketplaceWebService_Exception $ex) {
   echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");  echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n");
   echo("Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "\n");  echo("Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "\n");
   echo("Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "\n"); echo("XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "\n");
   echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $ex->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
    }
}


$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>xxxxxxxxxx</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>Inventory</MessageType>
<Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<OperationType>Update</OperationType>
<Inventory>
<SKU>VWDTA29E</SKU>
<Quantity>41</Quantity>
</Inventory>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>';


$xmlHandle = @fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');
fwrite($xmlHandle, $xml);
rewind($xmlHandle);
$md5 = base64_encode(md5(stream_get_contents($xmlHandle), true));

$parameters = array (
  'Merchant' => MERCHANT_ID,
  'FeedType' => '_POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_',
  'FeedContent' => $xmlHandle,
  'PurgeAndReplace' => false,
  'ContentMd5' => $md5,
);

$request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_SubmitFeedRequest($parameters);
echo $feedsubmissionid = SubmitFeed($service, $request);
```

How can I stop this information from being shown as this is only useful in testing and not production?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Found it - in Client.php in private function getDefaultCurlOptions rem out or set CURLOPT_VERBOSE = false!

Answer (score 0):

Can't help with that, I am facing same problem and its difficult to track your output as well. But try editing Feeds API class files by tracking down echo statements if there are  any!

> Best Luck...

Comment: There are no echo's, var-dumps, print_r's that I can see.  I have tried ob_start() and ob_end_flush() around the function call but that does not work either!  I am confused!

Comment: Found it - in Client.php in private function getDefaultCurlOptions rem out or set CURLOPT_VERBOSE = false! :-)